# How to pass variables from File A to a function in a class in File B

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I've been reading a lot of articles and websites, regarding classes and instances. But none have been able to provide me with a clear answer to this problem. How do you pass a variable, from one file, to a function, which is nested in a class, in another file?

On my database file, I have gotten the individual values from a given row. I need to pass these variables to a function on my Main file, which is situated in a class.

---

When running the code below I get the following error : `TypeError: PrintData() missing 1 required positional argument: 'DOB'`

```
def DisplayStudent(self):
    txtStudent = self.txtStudent.get()
    DisplayResults(txtStudent)

def PrintData(self, First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB):
    print(First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB)

    self.resultStudentFName.config(text = First)
```

---

And when running the code below this, I get a different error : `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

```
def DisplayStudent(self):
    txtStudent = self.txtStudent.get()
    DisplayResults(txtStudent)

def PrintData(First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB):
    print(First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB)

    self.resultStudentFName.config(text = First)
```

**Note:** This line of code is used on the Database file, the one with no class. It has not been changed for either of the following two sections of code above.

```
from Main import MainPage as MP
MP.PrintData(First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB)
```

And when I pass `self` as an argument to the `PrintData` line, it says `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

---

Any help with this code, along with any documentation relating to the use of classes, functions, modules and passing varibales between files would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, 
DavalliTV

Comment: your PrintData function doesn't do anything with the DOB so why are you passing it? And you don't need to pass self as an argument when you're calling the bound method

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am trying to printDOB as well! Edited OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what the issue was! I wasn't passing through `self`. Such a small issue/error can cause so much frustration! For those that look at this post in the future, make sure you carefully read what the error says, and make sure that when using classes, `self` is passed through. Thank you to Andrew and PydPiper for your efforts, I probably could've addressed the question better, but I appreciate you guys having a go!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your top snipit works except you just need to initialize the class when you pull it in:
`from Main import MainPage as MP
newMP = MP() # or pass in __init__ args as needed
newMP.PrintData(First, Last, Year, Tutor, DOB) # assuming these args have been previously defined`

Your bottom snipit doesn't work because it is a staticmethod without "self" in its argument list (therefore you cannot extend self. within the method)

Comment: When I tried this, it gives me a TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument; ‘root’. Yet when I put root in, it open the main file again!

Comment: Right so i don’t have full context here because the MP class wasnt part of your code snip it but __init__ is a initializer for the class. By the looks of your error code it takes 1 argument. Not sure what type of argument it takes until you paste the code here